# Spring Boot - Property 'dataSource' is required

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8

I would like to deploy a [spring boot app](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/springboot-jpademo) (github) to a tomcat 8.5 application server (which is running locally). I am following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) but I am getting the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:152) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.<init>(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:87) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.createHealthIndicator(DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:109) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.createHealthIndicator(DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:58) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d0a1dfd.createHealthIndicator(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.CompositeHealthIndicatorConfiguration.createHealthIndicator(CompositeHealthIndicatorConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.dbHealthIndicator(DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d0a1dfd.CGLIB$dbHealthIndicator$2(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d0a1dfd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7993816d.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d0a1dfd.dbHealthIndicator(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
```

**Tomcat 8.5**

This is my JNDI config in `context.xml` on the tomcat server

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/test.sqlite" 
            auth="Container" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            maxActive="100"
            maxIdle="30"
            maxWait="10000"
            driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
            url="jdbc:sqlite:/${catalina.home}/databases/test.sqlite"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory">
     </Resource>
```

**Spring boot**

The `DataSource` bean is configured here:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    private static Class<DemoApplication> applicationClass = DemoApplication.class;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFB = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFB.setJndiName("jdbc/test.sqlite");
        jndiObjectFB.setResourceRef(true);
        jndiObjectFB.setProxyInterface(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
        return (DataSource) jndiObjectFB.getObject();
    }
}
```

The `DataSource` should be used in the `CartDao`

```
public interface CartDao extends CrudRepository<Cart, Long> {

    Cart getById(long id);
}
```

The application properties are empty.

Here is the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what is happening is you spring is not able to instantiate a connection to the datasource.
Some possible causes for that might be:

1. maybe the sqllite dbfile is not reachable
2. maybe its location misconfigured in the context.xml
3. maybe check the permissions and credentials

To further determine the issue, I would first try to determine why spring ins't able to instantiate the datastore by enabling debug logging:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: I dont see @ Configuration
@ ComponentScan
@ EnableAutoConfiguration annotations .. can u add them and check ?